# glTexImage2DMultiSample - fixedsamplelocations set on false, getting samples count

Tags: opengl, glsl

I use `glTexImage2DMultiSample` with fixedsamplelocations parameter set on false. Then texels may have different samples count. How can I check samples count for a texel in the fragment shader ? Is the only solution to use `textureSamples` ([ARB_shader_texture_image_samples](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_texture_image_samples.txt)) ?

Comment: "Then texels may have different samples count. " No, why do you think so? The sample location may vary, but not the count per texel.

Comment: I believe the multisample will always be accessible up to the sample number you provided. And that ARB_shader_texture_image_samples will also return that value. So to my understanding, fixedsamplelocations only impact how internally those samples are sampled and how many times they are sampled to fill the full array.

Comment: @derhass, please see doc for the fixedsamplelocation: *Specifies whether the image will use identical sample locations and the same number of samples for all texels in the image, and the sample locations will not depend on the internal format or size of the image.*

Comment: That's about the number of samples which may be tested during rasterization, and the number of samples for which a fragment shader is invoked, **not** the number of samples stored in the actual texture. The sample count for a texture is a constant (the same `textureSamples` in GLSL returns, it doesn't take a texel location as input), and fetching samples from index 0` to `sampleCount-1` is always valid. The whole point of multisampling is that the _same_ output of _one_ fragment shader invocation may be written to _multiple_ samples.

Comment: @Irbis: "*Is the only solution to use textureSamples *" That wouldn't work either. `textureSamples` returns the sample count for the texture. It doesn't take a texel coordinate to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample count for an image is for the image, not for individual texels. So if some implementation assigns different numbers of samples to different texels, that's not something you can query. The implementation will have to *behave* as if it didn't do that, since all of OpenGL's APIs assume a fixed sample count for an image. This includes the APIs for reading and writing the current fragment's sample mask.